# undefined method `find_link' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x818e02e8> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, webrat

Rspec obviously hates me. I kinda hate him back.

```
#features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb
Then /^I should see the link "([^\"]*)"$/ do |linked_text|
 find_link(linked_text)
end

#link.feature
Then I should see the link "foo"
```

From terminal:

```
undefined method `find_link' for #<Cucumber::Rails::World:0x818e02e8> (NoMethodError)
./features/step_definitions/custom_steps.rb:115:in `/^I should see the link "([^\"]*)"$/'
```

My env.rb file:

```
#features/support/env.rb

# IMPORTANT: This file is generated by cucumber-rails - edit at your own peril.
# It is recommended to regenerate this file in the future when you upgrade to a 
# newer version of cucumber-rails. Consider adding your own code to a new file 
# instead of editing this one. Cucumber will automatically load all features/**/*.rb
# files.

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "cucumber"
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')

require 'cucumber/formatter/unicode' # Remove this line if you don't want Cucumber Unicode support
require 'cucumber/rails/world'
require 'cucumber/rails/active_record'
require 'cucumber/web/tableish'

require 'webrat'
require 'webrat/core/matchers'
require 'spec/stubs/cucumber'

Scenes::load

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :rails
  config.open_error_files = false # Set to true if you want error pages to pop up in the browser
end

# If you set this to false, any error raised from within your app will bubble 
# up to your step definition and out to cucumber unless you catch it somewhere
# on the way. You can make Rails rescue errors and render error pages on a
# per-scenario basis by tagging a scenario or feature with the @allow-rescue tag.
#
# If you set this to true, Rails will rescue all errors and render error
# pages, more or less in the same way your application would behave in the
# default production environment. It's not recommended to do this for all
# of your scenarios, as this makes it hard to discover errors in your application.
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

# If you set this to true, each scenario will run in a database transaction.
# You can still turn off transactions on a per-scenario basis, simply tagging 
# a feature or scenario with the @no-txn tag. If you are using Capybara,
# tagging with @culerity or @javascript will also turn transactions off.
#
# If you set this to false, transactions will be off for all scenarios,
# regardless of whether you use @no-txn or not.
#
# Beware that turning transactions off will leave data in your database 
# after each scenario, which can lead to hard-to-debug failures in 
# subsequent scenarios. If you do this, we recommend you create a Before
# block that will explicitly put your database in a known state.
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
# How to clean your database when transactions are turned off. See
# http://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner for more info.
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  begin
    require 'database_cleaner'
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  rescue LoadError => ignore_if_database_cleaner_not_present
  end
end
```

## What is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you none of your steps or helpers define this method.

Are you trying to use one of the helpers buried in Webrat?  It sounds like you want:

```
Webrat::Locators.find_link
```

Comment: undefined method `find_link' for Webrat::Locators:Module (NoMethodError)